# webpack plugin that adds other plugins

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin that acts as a *plugin wrapper*, loading configuration, files, etc. and **adding more plugins** to the current webpack compilation process.

In the `apply` function I create the plugins and then apply them against the original compiler, something like this:

```
apply(compiler) {
  const plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(options1),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(options2),
    ...
  ];

  plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
    plugin.apply(compiler);
  });
});
```

My plugin doesn't add any hook to the webpack compiler but let other plugins with add them. It works nice when the container project uses webpack 4... but I found an error when working with different webpack versions.

One of the *injected* plugins is the `html-webpack-plugin`, which is a dependency of my plugin:

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.3"
}
```

So as you can imagine, I inject instances of those 3 plugins.

The problem comes when the project using my plugin uses `webpack 3`, because at some point, inside `html-webpack-plugin` requires `NodeTemplatePlugin` which is under `html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/webpack`. So as far as I understand, `html-webpack-plugin` has its own `webpack` which is `webpack 4`. Since the original passed `compiler` comes from `webpack 3`, and the one expected in `NodeTemplatePlugin` is `webpack 4` I get an error when the latest tries to access `compiler.hooks.thisCompilation` because it doesn't exist in the compiler from `webpack 3`.

Funny thing is, in my package json webpack is defined as a `peerDependency` (same as in `html-webpack-plugin`) so it shouldn't be installed under the `node_modules` of my plugin.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0"
},
```

Any idea of why is this happening, or an alternative on how to inject plugins from another plugin?

If you need more context/code, you can check it here:
https://github.com/danikaze/generate-examples-index-webpack-plugin/blob/dev/src/ExamplesGenerator.js#L61

Comment: Try to get `html-webpack-plugin` to work with webpack 3 by itself. Presumably, only a specific version or versions of the package will be compatible with webpack 3. If so, you'll need to bundle multiple different versions of your app or bundle both and load the correct one.

Comment: @caesay that's a good idea. Two versions of the plugin, one for webpack 3 and other one for webpack 4... or only one version with both html-webpack-plugin versions and select the proper one based on webpack version I guess... but I'd need to bundle it...