# Setting global variables in a custom webpack plugin

Tags: webpack

I'm writing a Webpack plugin that, besides its main purpose, needs to add some global variables to the build. Normally, I would use `definePlugin` for declaring global variables, but I can't seem to easily replicate its behaviour inside my plugin. Is there any way to call `definePlugin` from inside of my plugin, or is there another way to declare global variables inside of a Webpack plugin?

I realise I can just copy the entirety of the `definePlugin` code, but I feel like there has to be a cleaner and more future-proof solution?

I could also pass a `--env=…` argument when running webpack, but this would require me to edit the command manually each time, and I'm not even sure I could reach it in the plugin that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in this question: [webpack plugin that adds other plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383087/webpack-plugin-that-adds-other-plugins)

I can run this to also call `DefinePlugin` during the build process:

```
apply(compiler: webpack.Compiler) {
    const versionId = '1234';

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        VERSION: JSON.stringify(versionId)
    }).apply(compiler);

   // other code
}
```